# How to install scons on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, scons

Can you please tell me how can I install scons on MacOSX?

I don't see a mac specified download from http://www.scons.org/

Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Download the tarball](http://www.scons.org/download.php) and then refer to the first chapter of the user guide, [Building and Installing SCons](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/c95.html). In short:

```
# cd scons-1.2.0
# python setup.py install
```

Comment: I needed to sudo it, but besides that, this worked a charm, and no macports required :)

Answer (score 44):

An alternative to MacPorts would be to use [HomeBrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew), where you'd just to

```
brew install scons
```

Answer (score 9):

Install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), then at the Terminal (Applications > Utilities > Terminal.app), type:

```
sudo port install scons
```

This command will automatically download and install scons for you. MacPorts requires that you have the developer tools installed, so if you don't, you will need to download and install the [Xcode 3 DVD](http://developer.apple.com/technology/tools.html).

NOTE 1: [Xcode 2.5](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=19907) is the last version of Xcode that will work on Mac OS X Tiger.

NOTE 2: This may seem awfully painful if you don't already have MacPorts installed. However, you really should go this route, as MacPorts makes it easy to update installed software, it automatically manages dependencies between software, and it makes it easier to install other packages in the future.

Comment: MacPorts is great, and I use it regularly. However, I try my hardest to steer clear of distribution-based package management when it comes to Python modules. I try to stick with virtualenv for isolating Python instances and pip for package management.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Python setuptools, the following will install scons-1.2.0 from sourceforge:

```
easy_install scons
```

But bear in mind the [issues people raise](http://lazypython.blogspot.com/2008/11/why-i-dont-use-easyinstall.html) with setuptools.

Also, keep in mind this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218891/multiple-versions-of-python-on-os-x-leopard/1219486#1219486) and the answers about virtualenv and pip for isolating Python environments.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a GUI installer for SCons on Mac OS X that I wrote available for download here:

https://github.com/rviney/scons-mac-installer

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.3.0 SCons should work without installing:

```
# get the source and switch to stable 2.3.0 version
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/ -r 2.3.0

# make sure to use Python 2 for now
python scons/src/scripts/scons.py
```

When running 2.3.0 from source, the `SCons.__version__` is not set correctly, so EnsureSConsVersion() will likely to fail if that's ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Installation via [pipx](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/)

1. Install `pipx` (if not yet done)

```
brew install pipx
pipx ensurepath
```

2. `pipx install scons`
3. Install manpages and configure manpath

```
cp ~/.local/pipx/venvs/scons/scons*.1 ~/.local/share/man/man1/
```

Insert

```
MANPATH=$HOME/.local/share/man/:$MANPATH;
```

into bashrc/zshrc.

**Advantages of pipx**

Install and run Python applications in isolated environments. (see [xkcd's take on Python dependencies](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/python_environment.png)).

Answer (score -2):

pull down SCons source and put it in /Library/Python/X.X/. Make sure you have the dir structure like this: /Library/Python/X.X/SCons/**init**.py

remember, import searches for modules, and /Library/Python/XXX is by default in the search path.