# How to install Python 3.1.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.4?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

Hi there I have downloaded the mac installer here, http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.1.2/ , & installed it. But when I run terminal & type python it says:

> Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29)
>   [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

What I want to know is, is it safe to run Update Shell Profile.command in the Python 3.1 folder ? or should I run python 3.1.2 separately ? If I should run python 3.1.2 separately, how do I do so ? also how do I start IDLE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there another python executable, perhaps `python31`?

You can also install other python versions via MacPorts if you need (although you'll still have to choose the right executable).

This should also be relevant: [Multiple versions of Python on OS X Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218891/multiple-versions-of-python-on-os-x-leopard)

Comment: >Is there another python executable, perhaps python31?

No

Comment: I DONT UNDERSTAND THIS ANSWER ! CAN SOMEONE PLEASE ANSWER MY QUESTIONS ?

Comment: Maybe `python3`? Start typing `python` and hit the tab key to see what it suggests.

Comment: This could be relevant too, although that would install Python via MacPorts and not via the official package: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Python

Comment: It says this:

python            python2.6         python3.1         pythonw2.6
python-config     python2.6-config  python3.1-config  pythonw3
python2.5         python3           pythonw           pythonw3.1
python2.5-config  python3-config    pythonw2.5

also what does python -v do ?

Comment: `python3.1` looks like what you're looking for. They all are different executable for different versions of Python. The `-v` option, available for all of them will display the exact version for each of them. (The name of the executable is just the name of what you call, not necessarily the name of what it is.)

Comment: so do I need to uninstall anything because all I need is python 3.1.2, are the other pythons in my list normal or is there some that seems to be manually installed ?

Comment: Python 2.5 and 2.6 come with OSX 10.6 out of the box and are part of the system. Don't uninstall them since some tools may rely on them.

Comment: The generic command name for most Python 3 installations (including the python.org OS X ones) is `python3`.  `python` is reserved for Python 2.