# How to add a path for Python 3.1 on a mac alongside Python 2.7?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, terminal, pythonpath

I'm a seventeen year old boy trying to learn Python.
I use the CBT Nuggets as my tutorial, however I've come across a problem.
I just switched to a macintosh and I don't know how to run python 3.1 code on the terminal and stop it from trying to run it with Python 2.7 (which is built in and I believe it's best not to mess with that.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218891/multiple-versions-of-python-on-os-x-leopard

Comment: Usually, `python3` will run the python 3 interpreter and just `python` will run the 2.x version. Is this not what you want?

Comment: @HampusNilsson thanks a lot I was confused as I thought I have to type: Python(3) -v on the terminal.
Sorry if this question was too stupid.

Comment: Appears that this problem is done - I am adding [closed]