# Minecraft 1.5.2 MCP

Tags: python, minecraft

I have a PowerPC Mac that is runing 10.5.8 mac OSX and has 2.5.1 python. When I try to run any file from the MCP folder that i download i get this error:
Macintosh-2:MCP Rosty$ bash
bash-3.2$ /Users/Rosty/Documents/MCP/updatemcp.sh 
/Users/Rosty/Documents/MCP/runtime/commands.py:137: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runtime/updatemcp.py", line 13, in 
    from commands import Commands
  File "/Users/Rosty/Documents/MCP/runtime/commands.py", line 137
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as fh:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  I have looked on the net but no one has the same problem... can some one plzzz help ???

Answer (score 0):

From the wiki: http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/MCP_Releases

You need to update Python to 2.7

edit:  A simple google search confirms, http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1752529-mcp-error/

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218891/multiple-versions-of-python-on-os-x-leopard

Comment: Power.PCHello i have mac PPC 10.5.8 and iv been trying to ru MCP on it But i had nothing but problems...
So is it posible to run MCP on Mac PPC? and if it is than what tools do i need ? help plzzzzz
-Rosty

Comment: Hi, you're going to have to tell us what you've attempted and, if possible, in understandable English.